# Sharepoint Lists retrieve schema LogicApp

Tags: list, sharepoint, schema, azure-logic-apps

Hi I have data in SharePoint lists.
Then I'm storing this data on the csv, because all the fields are strings my BI tool can't read some of them.
My questions is: Is that possible to retrieve SharePoint List Schema with the LogicApp?
This will solve my issues, then I will use it in Databricks processing and will apply to the cvcs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get File Properties and Metadata using below connector actions:

[image]

You can get items in a list like below using Get items action in SharePoint connector:

[image]

> Is that possible to retrieve SharePoint List Schema with the LogicApp?

AFAIK, this is not possible, ,you do not have a SharePoint connector in Logic apps where you get the data schema. [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#actions) says  which actions can be done. You can get metadata of file, file contents but not the Schema inside the file or list.

But to use SharePoint connector you can follow below design:

[image]

Output:

[image]

> then I will use it in Databricks processing and will apply to the cvcs.

You do not need Databricks to transform data, You can get the content of the SharePoint list/file from the output of Compose Action. You can use [JavaScript Inline connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code?tabs=consumption) to transform data.

[image]